# FindPeaks "expecting an image"

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages, image

I am trying to use FindPeaks for a list of data, but when I have tried to use it it returns an error.

I went to the help menu for the function to check that everything is in the correct format, and it appears to be fine. I have now tried to use the FindPeaks function with the examples that are provided in the help menu and the same error is returned which suggests it is a software problem.

I have attached a screenshot showing the problem. Can anyone figure out what is going on?

[image]

Comment: For reference I am using Mathematica version 10.3.0.0

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem using *Mathematica* v10.3.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Did you try to restart the kernel?

Comment: I am downloading the update to 10.3.1 now, so I will report back once I have tested the function with that

Comment: Resetting the Kernel worked. 

I guess that is Mathematica troubleshooting 101.
Thank you for your help! I feel like such a newb.

Any idea why that would have happened?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP solved the problem by quitting and restarting the local kernel. Therefore, there is really not question to answer.